# Is this proven ok? (Demorgans law set theory)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

[Want to prove 1st half of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE5Un.png)

So for the first half im trying to prove part one is a subset of part 2.

I let x be an element of (Intersection)Ai, then x cant be an element of the complement of the (Intersections) and Ai, meaning for all z in I there exists no z such that x is an element of Az. Therefore i say that there exists atleast one z in I where x is not an element of Az. Meaning part one is a subset of part 2.

Is this a correct way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe... but you have to supplement the argument with formulas, in order to improve the readibility.

Comment: In order to prove $A \subseteq B$ you have to consider $x \in A$ and show that $x \in B$.

Comment: Thus, you have to start from $x \in \overline {\bigcap A_i}$ and show that $x \in \bigcup \overline {A_i}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show that $\overline{\bigcap A_i} \subseteq \bigcup \overline{A_i}$. As @MauroALLEGRANZA says in the comments, to do this you should pick $x \in \overline{\bigcap A_i}$ and show that it follows that $x \in \bigcup \overline{A_i}$. However, your first statement is "Let $x \in \bigcap A_i$"; that is, you've picked $x \notin \overline{\bigcap A_i} $.  This is kind of like trying to show that all dogs are mammals by saying, "Let's first take an arbitrary bird..."

The straightforward approach to this is to allow $x \in \overline{\bigcap A_i}$.  This simply means $x$ is not in every $A_i$.  See if you can take it from here. If not, see below.

> \begin{align} x\in \overline{\bigcap A_i} &\implies  x \notin \bigcap A_i \\ & \implies \exists \: A_i \text{ such that } x \notin A_i\\  & \implies \exists \: A_i \text{ such that } x\in \overline{A_i}\\ &\implies x\in \bigcup \overline{A_i}\end{align}

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, exactly what i was asking about :)